# How can I do the opposite .include?

Tags: ruby

So the goal here is to print the index of the element if the element is in the array or print -1 if the element is not in the array. I have to do this using loops. PLEASE HELP!

```
def element_index(element, my_array)
  while my_array.map.include? element do
    puts my_array.index(element)
    break
  end

  until my_array.include? element do
    puts -1
    break
  end
end

p element_index("c", ["a","b","c"])
```

Comment: You can use `exclude?`

Answer (score 3):

If it's OK to use `Array#index`, then

```
def element_index(elem, collection)
  collection.index(elem) || -1
end
```

Or if it's a homework that you should not use `Array#index`, or you want to do this on arbitrary collections, then

```
def element_index(elem, collection)
  collection.each_with_index.reduce(-1) do |default, (curr, index)| 
    curr == elem ? (return index) : default
  end
end
```

By the way, I always turn to `Enumerable#reduce` when I want to iterate over a collection (array, map, set, ...) to compute one value.

Comment: I only use `reduce` if I want to _combine_ the input values in some way. To fetch a single value, I'd use `find`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an easy way but maybe it doesn't meet the criteria for "using loops":

```
def element_index(x, arr)
  arr.index(x) || -1
end

element_index("c", ["a","b","c"]) #=> 2
element_index("d", ["a","b","c"]) #=> -1
```

To explicitly use a loop:

```
def element_index(x, arr)
  arr.each_index.find { |i| arr[i] == x } || -1
end
```

As pointed out in the comments, we could instead write

```
arr.each_index.find(->{-1}) { |i| arr[i] == x }

element_index("c", ["a","b","c"]) #=>  2
element_index("d", ["a","b","c"]) #=> -1
```

Comment: I see my first suggestion is the same as that proposed earlier by @aetherus.

Comment: This comment is not relevant to the OP's question, but I think it was a very smart move for Matz to make `0` truthy, so we can just type `if arr.index(foo)` instead of `if arr.index(foo) >= 0`

Comment: `find` also takes a default value, although it has to be passed as a proc: `arr.find(->{-1}) { |i| arr[i] == x }`

Comment: I thank @Stefan for mentioning that [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) accepts as an argument a default proc. I didn''t know that. (His last comment concerned an earlier revision.)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an assignment, but I'll first cover this as if it were real code because it's teaching you some not-so-great Ruby.

Ruby has a method for doing this, [Array#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-index). It returns the index of the *first* matching element (there can be more than one), or `nil`.

```
p ["a","b","c"].index("c")  # 2
p ["a","b","c"].index("d")  # nil
```

Returning -1 is inadvisable. [`nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html) is a safer "this thing does not exist" value because its never a valid value, always false (-1 and 0 are true in Ruby), and does not compare equal to anything but itself. Returning -1 indicates whomever came up with this exercise is converting it from another language like C.

If you must, a simple wrapper will do.

```
def element_index(element, array)
    idx = array.index(element)
    if idx == nil
        return -1
    else
        return idx
    end
end
```

---

> *I have to do this using loops.*

Ok, it's homework. Let's rewrite `Array#index`.

The basic idea is to loop through each element until you find one which matches. Iterating through each element of an array is done with `Array#each`, but you need each index, that's done with [`Array#each_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-each_index). The element can be then gotten with `array[idx]`.

```
def index(array, want)
    # Run the block for each index of the array.
    # idx will be assigned the index: 0, 1, 2, ...
    array.each_index { |idx|
        # If it's the element we want, return the index immediately.
        # No need to spend more time searching.
        if array[idx] == want
            return idx
        end
    }

    # Otherwise return -1.
    # nil is better, but the assignment wants -1. 
    return -1
end

# It's better to put the thing you're working on first,
# and the thing you're looking for second.
# Its like verb( subject, object ) or subject.verb(object) if this were a method.
p index(["a","b","c"], "c")
p index(["a","b","c"], "d")
```

Get used to using `list.each { |thing| ... }`, that's how you loop in Ruby, along with [many other similar methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html). There's little call for `while` and `for` loops in Ruby. Instead, you ask the object to loop and tell it what to do with each thing. It's very powerful.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to do this using loops.

You approach is very creative. You have re-created an `if` statement using a `while` loop:

```
while expression do
  # ...
  break
end
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if expression
  # ...
end
```

With `expression` being something like `array.include? element`.

> How can I do the opposite?

To invert a (boolean) expression, you just prepend [`!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-21):

```
if !expression
  # ...
end
```

Applied to your `while`-hack:

```
while !expression do
  # ...
  break
end
```

The whole method would look like this:

```
def element_index(element, my_array)
  while my_array.include? element do
    puts my_array.index(element)
    break
  end

  while !my_array.include? element do
    puts -1
    break
  end
end

element_index("c", ["a","b","c"])
# prints 2
element_index("d", ["a","b","c"])
# prints -1
```

As I said at the beginning, this approach is very "creative". You are probably supposed to find the index using a loop (see [Schwern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44426465/477037)) instead of calling the built-in `index`.